# How to read updateDescription from Debezium MongoDB Connector in Apache Camel?

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel, camel-kafka-connector, debezium-connect

I am using MongoDB 6.0+ version , Debezium 2.3.2-Final version and apache camel version 4.2.0.

I am using apache camel for listening event from Debezium and posting to kafka topic.
logging both header and body in below way:

```
from("Debezium-cdc-listener")
.log("${header})
.log("${body})
.to("kafka");
```

As per the debezium doc,
There is a new structured field updateDescription with a few additional fields in this case:

1. updatedFields is a string field that contains the JSON representation of the updated document fields with their values
2. removedFields is a list of field names that were removed from the document
3. truncatedArrays is a list of arrays in the document that were truncated

I am able to see this updated fields in mongoDB oplog and capture.mode=*_pre_image i have added

**Issue :**
I am not getting this updateDescription in my camel's header or body. I need updatedFields. How to fetch that in camel ?